# How to bind 'C-u M-x shell' to 'C-c s'?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

I would like to define the keybinding `C-c s` which should start a new shell in the current directory (so `C-c s` should behave like `C-u M-x shell`). I know how to define a keybinding based on a function (e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'shell)`), but this problem here is more of the sort "defining a keybinding by another keybinding" (if I try `C-h k` and then type `C-u M-x shell`, I get the help for `C-u` alone (right after typing it)).

Comment: Even if it is a duplicate, I would have not found it. If I had known `universal-prefix-argument`, I would have perhaps found it. I think there is value in having a version with `C-u`... in the title (which is supported by the number of upvotes in the small amount of time). But thanks for creating the link to the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `universal-prefix-argument` and call `shell` interactively:

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c s")
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
     (call-interactively #'shell))))
```